# Why does $\nabla_{X}Y$ depend only on $X_{p}$? Lee's book on Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

**I am trying to understand the following theorem from Lee's book about Riemannian geometry. I had a look at several books but unfortunaletly I am still not quite sure if I get it.**

[image]

**Question 1:** Why does he assume w.l.o.g. that $X_{p}=0$. I would say that the proof applied to $X(p)-\tilde{X}(p)=0$ gives the disered result, but why can't it be done "directly" as in the following excerpt. I would have done it this way too.

[image]

**Question 2:** I had a look at Boothby's book and what I dont't understand is why he constructs a vector field that agrees with $X$ in a nhd. Is it just supposed to be a proof of existence in the sense that we can actually find such a vector field? Furthermore could it be that there are some typos? For example in the the equation above the last paragraph.
[image]
I know it is quite a long question bit I would really appreciate some help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Although I don't have the book at hand, I guess Proposition 4.3 is a cutoff argument similar to those in Bootley's Corollary 3.5

Comment: For Q1) Showing that $\left(\nabla_X Y\right)(p)$ only depends on $X(p)$ is saying that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are vector fields with $X_1(p)=X_2(p)$, then $\left(\nabla_{X_1}Y\right)(p) = \left(\nabla_{X_2}Y \right)(p)$. By linearity, this is equivalent to saying that $\left(\nabla_{X_1-X_2}Y\right)(p) = 0$. Finally, saying $\left(\nabla_XY\right)(p)$ only depends on $X(p)$ is equivalent to saying that $(\nabla_{X}Y)(p) = $ for all $X$ such that $X(p) = 0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar What do you mean by cutoff argument? I think both use bump functions. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yeah. By cutoff I mean a bump function argument.

Comment: @Didier I am not sure about the last line. Do you mean $\nabla_{X}Y(p)$ gives the same value for every vector field which satisfies $X(p)=0$?

Comment: @Hans I meant that the function $ X \mapsto (\nabla_{X}Y)(p)$ only depends on the value $X(p)$ (and not on the local behaviour of $X$ around $p$) is equivalent to saying that $(\nabla_XY)(p)=0$ for every $X$ such that $X(p) = 0$.

Comment: Compare with the fact that $(\nabla_XY)(p)$ can be non zero even if $Y(p) = 0$ (for example, take $X = \partial_x$, $Y = x \partial_y$ and $p = (0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the euclidean metric. Then $Y(p) = 0$ but $(\nabla_XY)(p) = \partial_y |_{p}$)

Comment: This is all easy to verify, if you use local coordinates. I'm all for avoiding coordinates when *using* the connection, but for technical details like this, local coordinates often provide the easiest approach.

Comment: For your second question, i think it is because connection is an operator that act on global vector fields. If we have a local vector field $X$ that defined in a nbhd $U$, we cannot feed this directly to out connection. In Lee's, we can get away with this with Proposition 4.3. But there's no such proposition in Boothby. So in Boothby we can work around this problem by extending $X$ directly. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482776/connection-on-vector-bundle-prove-that-nabla-x-yp-0-if-xp-0)